# Symfony PHPUnit - Refresh Database only after all tests

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, api-platform.com, testcase

I use *HautelookAliceBundlePhpUnitRefreshDatabaseTrait* to perform my tests. But the problem with that is that my data is reset at each test. What I would like is some kind of instance where I can play with my data (insert, modify, delete ...) during my tests and at the end of all the tests, I reset the database.

Comment: Basically you want to make your tests dependents on each other: that's a terrible practice. Drop this idea then write independent tests. More information [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development#Practices_to_avoid,_or_%22anti-patterns%22).

Comment: Not necessarily. I'm resetting my database before my tests (not for every single test), but without depending on each other. As long as test B doesn't fail because test A didn't run (or failed), I don't see a problem.